# Database query execution

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I have an application in C# and database is sqlite(.db3). Where I have 2 functions.

```
String sConnectionString = "Data Source=mydb.db3;Version=3;Password=123456;";
private void longitudinalProfileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    saveProject(iProjectID);
    computeArea(iProjectID);
}

public int saveProject(iProjectID)
{
    SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
    SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd_PostWork;
    SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd_Design;
    sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection(sConnectionString);
    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "Delete from prework where pid = " + iProjectID + ";";
    sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "Insert into prework (pid, chainage, date) values (" + iProjectID + "," + fChainagePostwork + ",'" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "');";
    sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlite_conn.Close();
return 1;
}

public int computeArea(iProjectID)
{
    SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
    SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd_PostWork;
    SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd_Design;
    sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection(sConnectionString);
    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "Delete from postwork where pid = " + iProjectID + ";";
    sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "Insert into postwork (pid, chainage, date) values (" + iProjectID + "," + fChainagePostwork + ",'" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "');";
    sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlite_conn.Close();
return 1;
}
```

saveProject() function works properly.
But in computeArea() function, the query don't show any error but database/table don't update/insert/delete.

If I call longitudinalProfileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) second time then it works properly.

But in previous time it worked properly.
What is the problem?

Comment: What is the schema of the two tables? You are using string concatenation which, apart from exposing you to SQL Injection attacks, will break due to type conversion errors. If one table expects a string and another expects a float, the second will fail if you try to enter a string with an unexpected decimal separator.

Comment: BTW your code isn't valid C# code. `computeArea(iProjectID)` isn't a valid function declaration.  Post code that actually compiles, including any exception handling code that may be hiding what's wrong

Comment: Actually 2nd function works properly if I call it individually. And if I call same way as the question, then it doesn't show any error. @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score -2):

You could use 'using block' like that,

```
String sConnectionString = "Data Source=mydb.db3;Version=3;Password=123456;";
private void longitudinalProfileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    saveProject(iProjectID);
    computeArea(iProjectID);
}

saveProject(iProjectID)
{
    SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
    SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd_PostWork;
    SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd_Design;
    using (sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection(sConnectionString))
    {
        sqlite_conn.Open();
        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "Delete from prework where pid = " + iProjectID + ";";
        sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "Insert into prework (pid, chainage, date) values (" + iProjectID + "," + fChainagePostwork + ",'" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "');";
        sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

computeArea(iProjectID)
{
    SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
    SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd_PostWork;
    SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd_Design;

    using (sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection(sConnectionString))
    {
        sqlite_conn.Open();
        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "Delete from postwork where pid = " + iProjectID + ";";
        sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "Insert into postwork (pid, chainage, date) values (" + iProjectID + "," + fChainagePostwork + ",'" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "');";
        sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: I added "sqlite_conn.Open();"